# Android - forName() method ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, reflection

I was trying to test how `forName()` works, but I'm getting `ClassNotFoundException` for some reason. Here's my code:

```
package practicePackage;

import java.lang.Class;

public class mainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Class testSar = Class.forName("practicePackage.Animal");
            testSar.eat();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Here's the complete view of my package
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Here's my `Animal.java` file:

```
package practicePackage;

public class Animal {
    int hunger;
    char[] food;
    int[] pos;
    int[] boundary;

    public Animal()
    {
        System.out.println("Animal Constructed..");
    }

    public void makeNoise()
    {
        System.out.println("Animal noise..");
    }

    public void eat()
    {
        System.out.println("Animal eat..");
    }

    public void sleep()
    {
        System.out.println("Animal sleep..");
    }

    public void roam()
    {
        System.out.println("Animal roam..");
    }

}
```

Comment: can you also copy and paste the Animal.java file?

Comment: Is this a compile error or a runtime crash?

Comment: in my code ( also mentioned in my question), the statement testSar.eat() is erroneous ( intellisense is unable to find the eat() function ) which means testSar isn't an instance of class Animal

Comment: @hoomi code pasted in edit

Comment: where have you reached with this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are calling the eat method is wrong. When you do

```
Class testSar = Class.forName("practicePackage.Animal");
```

It return the class of Animal not an instance of Animal. The right way of doing it is to add the following lines:

```
Animal instanceAnimal = (Animal)testStar.newInstance();
instanceAnimal.eat()
```

I am not sure about the ClassNotFoundException though. Everything looks fine in your code except for what I mentioned above.

Maybe double check if your file has not been excluded from the build path or try using another class and see if it happens for other classes as well

Comment: This time(after modifying as you suggested), I'm getting an IllegalAccessException

Comment: A better option would be to use 'new Animal()'. Using reflection for this case is overkill, and causing a lot of unneeded confusion.

Comment: If you are not practicing reflection then @Smith_61 is valid. Regarding the exception make the constructor public and it should fix it

Comment: If you are practicing reflection, please follow Oracle's reflection trails found here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/. It will provide a much more complete overview how the pitfalls, and gotchas found within the API.

Answer (score 3):

In the `2 quick fixes available` panel, click on `Surround with try/catch`. This is how methods like `forname()` are supposed to be used: there is the possibility that a certain class may not always be available, or it may be there and yet it may not have the methods you are looking for.

If you want to really call the `eat()` method, what you can do is:

```
Animal animal = (Animal) testSar.newInstance();
animal.eat();
```

Try this. It should work.

Comment: I tried casing it with try-catch too.. refering to the code in my question, class testSar = Class.forName("practicePackage.Animal"); testSar.eat(); the intellisense doesn't show eat() method, which means that testSar is not an object of class Animal. ( eat() is a member function of my class Animal() )

Comment: The object returned by Class.forName() is the Class object for the given name. This is just a holder for a bunch of metadata about a given class. You should instead use 'new Animal()'

Comment: `Smith_61` is right. You cannot call the `eat()` method or any other method of the `Animal` class. That's because the `testSar` object is an instance of `Class` that contains metadata of the `Animal` class. It isn't an instance of the `Animal` class. For a workaround, see my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

It refers that the method `forName` could rise that kind of **exception** if the class you want is not found e.g. **"practicePackage.Animal"** class. Just cast that sentence with try-catch or add throws declaration to that method.

And if you want to call that method in Animal class you have to create an instance of that class:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("practicePackage.Animal");
Animal testSar = (Animal) clazz.newInstance();
testSar.eat();
```

Comment: I tried casing it with try-catch too.. refering to the code in my question, class testSar = Class.forName("practicePackage.Animal");
            testSar.eat(); the intellisense doesn't show eat() method, which means that testSar is not an object of class Animal. ( eat() is a member function of my class Animal() )

Comment: I saved the file and tried it again.. still the error

Comment: well Class doesnt have an eat-method, you need to cast it to Animal class!

Comment: I am guessing eat method is not a Class method but and instance method. Even casting the class to Animal class does not have the eat method since it is not an instance of Animal.

Answer (score 0):

You can, with a successfully loaded class that has a default constructor/with no arguments:

```
Class<Animal> testSar = (Class<Animal>)Class.forName("practicePackage.Animal");
testSar.newInstance().eat();
```